# nodejs https server certificate error

Tags: node.js

I am unable to use HTTPS and send the index.html to the client.

Nodejs code:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
var fs = require('fs');
var https = require('https');
var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('key.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('cert.pem'),
  rejectUnauthorized: false
};
https.createServer(options, function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200);
  res.end("hello world\n");
}).listen(443);
https.get('/', function(request, response){
  response.sendFile('/home/ubuntu/index.html');
});
```

I get this error, should I be calling options in the https.get function?

```
`events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: DEPTH_ZERO_SELF_SIGNED_CERT`
```

Comment: what version of node are you using?

Comment: nodejs --version
v0.10.25

Comment: Did you try using a proper boolean for `rejectUnauthorized`, instead of a string?

Comment: Yes the only reason it shows as a string is because I was playing around with it to see if that was the problem...currently the option looks like this `rejectUnauthorized: false`

Comment: have you tried `process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0";`

Comment: It's worth noting that HTTPS in node is a bit of a PITA. I opted to use http as normal, and have nginx handle the HTTPS part (and reverse proxy onto Node behind the scenes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0"; – Maverick976